# docker-compose redis won't start : docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

I try to get started with docker-compose : https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ (i've  exactly the files described there)

I do it on a debian (stretch) server.
It all goes well until I do docker-compose up:
the web service goes up all right but redis service can't start docker-entrypoint.sh and exits.

```
root@12456:~/composeTest# docker-compose up
Creating network "composetest_default" with the default driver
Creating composetest_redis_1 ... done
Creating composetest_web_1   ... done
Attaching to composetest_redis_1, composetest_web_1
redis_1  | su-exec: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
composetest_redis_1 exited with code 1
...
web_1    |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I feel like I'm the only one with this issue, so maybe it's something so dumb everybody figured it out right away!

Thanks.

Comment: What's in your docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Hi, step 3 here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: Maybe you need to run the whole thing with `sudo`? e.g. `sudo docker-compose up`. Alternatively you may need to change the user inside your dockerfile (using the `USER` command).